# Não consigo mostrar todo resultado do analisador léxico

Tags: java, eclipse

Meu professor passou um trabalho sobre compiladores. Ele quer que eu faça um Analisador Léxico.

Consegui fazer boa parte do código, mas não consigo mostrar o resultado.
Sou iniciante em Java e estou utilizando o Eclipse.

O resultado que o Professor quer que apareça (com qualquer resultado, não precisa ter uma entrada.) :

Exemplo:

> **Expressão:** "8 + 8 = 16"

Resultado: (O código vai analisar se essa entrada é correta, caso não esteja vai dizer error).

> **Digito:** 8
>   **Operador:** +
>   **Digito:** 8
>   **Igualdade:** =
>   **Digito:** 16

Meu código:

```java
**package lexico;**

import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Lexico {
    public static void main (String []args) {

        String code  = "59-8=51";
        int c = 0;


        Map<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<>();
            tokens.put("[0-9]+", "[Digito:]");
            tokens.put("[/+/-]+", "[Operador:]");
            tokens.put("[/=]+", "[Igualdade: ]");

        while(c < code.length()) {

            for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : tokens.entrySet()) {

                Pattern verificador = Pattern.compile(entry.getKey());
                Matcher ve = verificador.matcher(code);


                if(ve.find() && ve.start() == c) {
                    System.out.println(entry.getValue() + ve.group());  
                    c = c + ve.group().length();
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

O resultado do meu código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de dar a resposta e mostrar-te o código, quero dizer-te que o código tem comentários que indicam a razão pela qual acrescentei/modifiquei o teu código. Espero que esteja tudo legível e compreensível.

```
    String code  = "59-8-10=41"; // Modifiquei o texto de entrada com mais uma substração apenas para teste.
    int c = 0;


    Map<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<>();
        tokens.put("[0-9]+", "[Digito:]");
        tokens.put("[/+/-]+", "[Operador:]");
        tokens.put("[/=]+", "[Igualdade: ]");

    while(c < code.length()) {

        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : tokens.entrySet()) {

            Pattern verificador = Pattern.compile(entry.getKey());
            Matcher ve = verificador.matcher(code).region(c, code.length()); // Indicar qual a região a analisar. Começa sempre no valor da variável c (já que esta tem qual o último index analisado) até ao comprimento da palavra de entrada.

            if(ve.find() && ve.start() == c) {
                System.out.println(entry.getValue() + ve.group());
                c += ve.group().length();
                break; // Quando o grupo deu match tens de sair do ciclo for para garantir que todas as expressões regulares são novamente percorridas para o novo grupo.
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Blz mano. Ajudou bastante. Vlw